Why does declaring a variable without a keyword result in a SyntaxError for var and const, but not for let in JavaScript?
Declaring variable in JS without keyword.
I get SyntaxError when I declare variable like var = 1 or const = 1. But I don't get this error when i declare like let = 1. Why is this happening?


var = 1; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=' (at index.js:2:5)





const = 1; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=' (at index.js:2:5)





let = 1; // NO ERROR.




Outside of strict mode, let can be a valid variable name.  (Though I certainly wouldn't recommend using it as such.)  var and const cannot.  The linked duplicate goes further into the history of reserved keywords.

What is it that you expect var = 1 to even mean?

var and const are reserved keywords ( can't be used as variable names), let in some environments is not a reserved keyword and in this situation, it is considered as a variable name.


let = 1;

console.log(let)




It may be what you mean by "some environments" but let is reserved in strict mode.

@Jafarl1, like a browser environment but as Alex mentioned with "use strict" mode it will be a reserved keyword.

Then it turns out that the let is reserved only in strict mode, but var and const in both?

@Jafarl1, yes var and const are reserved words in both.
